# Creating links to a page that displays specific rows in my database w/ django?

Tags: django, django-views

I created a watered down project based of my more complex project for this question to help deliver my question more effectively. I'll include the code below for future viewers of this post but for ease/convenience [here](https://gitlab.com/shanedora/mult_pages_problem) is the gitlab repository url.

I have a model "NotesModel" that models the architecture of a note that you might take during the day. It's quite simple there's a 'title', 'tag' and of course the main part which I call the 'content'. The tag is like a tag you link to your stack overflow post. It's just to help identify the topic that a particular note might be about.

In my function based view I query every row in my database and hand it off to my `render(.., .., {'notes': notes})` function as you'll see below. With some html/bootstrap styling I display every item from the 'tag' column in my database as a label which is linkable with the ...a href=""... syntax as such.

```
    {% for note in notes %}
        <span class="label label-primary" id="tags">
            <a id="theurl" href="this is where my confusion is">
            {{note.tag}}
            </a>
        </span>
    {% endfor %}
```

I entered some basic notes already and taken a screen-shot to help show you what my page looks like in hope that it better explains the behavior I want which I explain next.

[Screen-shot](https://i.imgur.com/GTvqdl0.png)

The behavior that I want is to treat this label as a actual tag you might find on some forum website. The behavior is as follows...

1) The user clicks on the label
2) Django directs the user to another page
3) The rows in the database that the attribute 'tag' (being the column) matches the name of the label will be displayed.

Let me explain a bit more. From the picture above you can see there are already four notes (being four rows in database terminology) entered into the database. Therefore, the 'tag' attribute (being the 'tag' column in database terminology) has four instances being **starwars**, **startrek**, **avp**, and another **starwars** instance. I want to be able to click on the tag **starwars** and it directs me to another page that displays all notes with the 'tag' **starwars**. Same goes for the other tags. If I click on **startrek** then I want this to direct me to another page that displays all notes with the 'tag' **startrek**.

I did at one point try creating another page in my templates folder and then used a query set filter like the following that I passed off to the template.

```
queryset = NotesModel.objects.filter(tag__icontains='starwars')
```

Then I just typed the direct link to that page in the ...a href=""... piece of code. However, there's two problems with this solution...

1 It only works for **starwars**
2 If i did it this way I would have to create x number of page.html files in my templates folder with an equal amount of x number of function based views with the above queryset. This is more static and not a dynamic way of doing things so how do I achieve such a task?

The following are files in my project as of now. As I said earlier i'm including the gitlab repository url above should you want to pull the project down yourself.

**the_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**the_app/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class NotesModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**the_app/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import NotesModel
class NotesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NotesModel
        fields = ['title', 'tag', 'content']
```

**the_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import NotesModel
from .forms import NotesForm

def home(request):

    # Grab the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NotesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = NotesForm()
    else:
        form = NotesForm()

    # Grab the data from the database
    notes = NotesModel.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'the_app/page_home.html', {'form': form, 'notes': notes})
```

**the_app/templates/the_app/base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mystyle.css' %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    {% block notesform %}{% endblock notesform %}
</div>
<div>
    {% block notetags %}{% endblock notetags %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**the_app/templates/the_app/page_home.html**

```
{% extends "the_app/base.html" %}

{% block notesform %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock notesform %}

{% block notetags %}
    {% for note in notes %}
        <span class="label label-primary" id="tags">
            <!-- I didn't know what to put here so i used google's url as a place holder-->
            <a id="theurl" href="https://www.google.com">
            {{note.tag}}
            </a>
        </span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock notetags %}
```

Comment: First of all don't write so long question, it may get unnoticed due to that. Only add the exact problem. In your case you are adding starwars in the quesyset so it will only work for starwars not for anything else.I'm adding an answer that will help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem, `queryset = NotesModel.objects.filter(tag__icontains='starwars')` your tag is only containing starwars. So it will not find other tags.

```
class TagPostView(ListView):
   model = NoteModel
   template_name = '....'
   context_object_name = 'all_notes_of_this_tag'

   def get_queryset(self):
      result = super(PostTagView, self).get_queryset()
      query = self.request.GET.get('q')
      if query:
         postresult = NoteModel.objects.filter(tag__icontains=query)
         result = postresult
      else:
         result = None
      return result
```

Now you can pass label as q and it will search for that tag and show the result. All you need is only one template for this.

In template you can use,

```
{% for note in all_notes_of_this_tag %}
{{note.title}}
#..
{% endfor %}
```

This will solve all three requirements.

Comment: what is the purpose to 'q' and if able could you refer a reference other than the documentation that might help me grasp the logic here inside get_queryset? I get that we are overloading it here but I believe there's a gap in my knowledge here on "requests" in general. There's alot of abstraction going on here.

Comment: q here is used to retrieve the input query. You have seen it when you google anything it comes like https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow , which basically means the input query is stackoverflow here. In your case you can add tag names as query so it will return as q=#tagname here. And about documentation, sorry I don't have any proper link. However you can search it in google to find out more.